# Linker problems with MacPorts and XCode

Tags: xcode, linker, linker-errors, macports

I constantly get errors like `ld: building for iOS simulator, but linking against dylib built for MacOSX file '/opt/local/lib/libz.dylib' for architecture x86_64...`.

Since `MacPorts` is the pretty much the only program that writes anything in `/opt/local` I changed the name `/opt/` to `/opt_/`, and my projects ran fine, but still give me the error `Directory not found for option '-L/opt/local/lib'`.

I checked the manual for `ld` and the `-L` argument basically tells the linker the path to search for libraries. I checked my XCode project, but couldn't find any traces of it mentioning `/opt/local/lib/` or even `$(something)/lib`.

Where else could I look to remove the search path `/opt/local/lib/` for libraries? Or is there any place where I can exclude certain paths from ever being searched?

Btw: I'm using the latest XCode Beta version 6.0 (6A313)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What are you using to build this project?  Is it an Xcode project?  If so, check the build settings for your target and search for "SEARCH_PATHS" in the search field.  That will turn up various build settings that you may have inadvertently set, including LIBRARY_SEARCH_PATHS, HEADER_SEARCH_PATHS, etc.

You might just want to grep your project file for '/opt/' and see where it's coming in.

If you're using cmake or autoconf as your build system, you probably have the LDFLAGS environment variable set to include -L/opt/local/lib

Comment: Thanks for the tips. I already thoroughly checked the `SEARCH_PATHS` though. There is nothing that points to `/opt/local/bin`. The project is an iOS project build with the standard Apple LLVM 6.0.

Comment: That doesn't really respond to my point or question.  What is the build system?  Are you using Xcode?  As for /opt/local/bin, that has nothing to do with it.  Something is adding -L/opt/local/lib to your LDFLAGS.  If you're using Xcode, that's coming in via LIBRARY_SEARCH_FLAGS or OTHER_LINKER_FLAGS.  As mentioned in my answer, I suggest you just grep for /opt/local in your project file and associated xcconfigs.

Comment: Maybe pkg-config is involved, too? Try removing /opt/local/bin from your `$PATH` before building (if it was in there in the first place, of course).

Comment: @JeremyHuddlestonSequoia Sorry, I thought it was clear that I'm using XCode as a build system. So to answer your questions: Yes, I'm using XCode as a build system, and I also grepped for {opt/local/lib, /opt/local/, /lib}, but didn't find a single reference anywhere in the project, that's why I said in the original questions `I checked my XCode project, but couldn't find any traces of it mentioning /opt/local/lib/ or even $(something)/lib.`

Comment: @neverpanic I thought the same and just checked my $PATH again. Indeed I had an `export LIBRARY_PATH=/opt/local/lib` in my `zshrc` config file. But even after removing that line the error is still the same. I still think the error is hidden in here somewhere though.

Comment: Your zshrc would impact what you do from the command line via xcodebuild but would not impact what you do from Xcode.app as it won't inherit that environment.  That is really bizarre.  Are you using any xcconfigs that are not in your project?  Can you strip down your project for me to look at (or just host the project.pbxproj file somewhere)?

Comment: @JeremyHuddlestonSequoia Thanks for your help! The projects file itself is in a workspace file, because I'm using CocoaPods as well. Pods shouldn't interfere here, right? So I'll just upload the project file?

Comment: @JeremyHuddlestonSequoia Here is the project file (only valid for the next 24h): http://pastebin.com/1qJNjkde

Comment: Yeah, I don't see anything odd in that project file.  Perhaps something in the Pods.xcconfig that is inherited from?  If you feel comfortable pasting the entire build log, that might help as well.

Comment: @JeremyHuddlestonSequoia Here is the build log: http://pastebin.com/00bgpCd2 I couldn't see anything suspicious in the Pods.xcconfig file, but for the sake of finding the error: http://pastebin.com/TR8fQBUV

Comment: There is no explicit -L/opt/local/lib in the command line passed to clang, thus clang is adding it when executing the linker.  This is usually due to LIBRARY_PATH being set.  I'm curious if you have it set somewhere other than your .zshrc file.  Remove it from .zshrc and try to figure out where else it might be coming from (maybe /etc/launchd.conf?).  I suggest you add an empty script phase early in this target and enable the checkbox that will show the environment variables.  Then look at the build log to see if LIBRARY_PATH is set (or if there is something else with /opt/local in it).

Comment: @JeremyHuddlestonSequoia Thanks again. I hope I can find some time today or tomorrow to take a look at it. Will report back.